# What will happen when I 'cat' 'ksh'?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ksh, cat

I used the following command in my unix box.

```
$ cat ksh
```

And it gave a rolling log of latin and greek letters and symbols and it kept on going with no signs of stopping. Eventually I had to close my connection tool to stop it.

I was just wondering what was it displaying?

Comment: You missed the command!

Comment: No, he failed at formatting.  Fixed that.

Comment: Dude, that's what happens when you "cat" a binary file :)

Comment: If you're up for a real thrill, try to "type" an .exe in a Windows command prompt.  You'll get the Latin and Greek letters, the symbols, *and* it will even beep at you, too! ;)

Comment: Not sure that this is a programming question; perhaps superuser would make more sense?

Comment: You can also use the "strings" command to see the text in a file: `cd /bin;strings ls|less`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you were running `cat` on the actual ksh binary file, then you were seeing the raw machine code of the ksh program being interpreted as if it was human-readable text.  Of course, it wasn't, so the characters displayed were random characters from your terminal's character set, plus control and other non-printable characters.

Some of the control characters in a binary file can mess up your terminal's state.  If you close the connection, that's fine, but you can also recover without closing your connection by pressing control-C to stop the process and then typing "reset" and pressing enter.

Comment: Addendum: the command `hd $(which ksh) | less` will display the same data (the contents of the `ksh` executable) in a format that humans can actually get useful information out of.

Comment: `bash: hd: command not found`

Comment: The bytes of `ksh` may be seen with `od -tx1 ksh`.

Comment: On my Linux box (Debian) `hd` comes from the `bsdmainutils` package.  I don't know where to get it for other distributions.  OSX doesn't have `hd` but it does have `hexdump` which does something similar (sadly, it lacks the ASCII column which `hd` provides).

Comment: Vim comes with `xxd`, and util-linux has `hexdump -C`. @Zack, does OSX `hexdump` support `-C`?

Comment: It does! I didn't realize this because there is no manpage.

Answer (score 0):

A binary executable is a file like any other; its contents aren't guaranteed to make sense to humans, and usually don't.  `cat` won't stop you from displaying it, because it can't really tell the difference between an executable and (say) a text file with a lot of non-ISO-8859-1 Unicode in it.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you were trying to print the contents of a binary file. I have done that a few times before by accident, and it almost always crashes putty. Now, for some real fun, go ahead and do `cat /dev/urandom`: always a good time. (`urandom` makes an awesome random data generator for things such as generating passwords, coin flips, etc., plus it is "true" random data because this data is pulled from the entropy pool (which is based on things such as electrical noise, etc., that the server monitors).)